# Erro ao consumir api Swagger do portal da transparencia

Tags: jquery, cors, cross-domain, swagger

Utilizando este código pra consumir a api está dando um erro no cross-domain

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$('#seguro').click(function(){
  cpf = $('#cpf').val();
  endapitrans = "http://www.transparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/seguro-defeso-codigo?codigo="+ cpf +"&pagina=1";

  $.getJSON(endapitrans, function(result){
    $.each(result, function(id, pessoaSeguroDefeso){
      for(var i=0;result.length>i;i++){
        $("#api").append(result[i].id + " - " + result[i].pessoaSeguroDefeso.nome + "<br>");
      }
    });
  });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa incluir o dominio `demo.syspesca.com.br` na lista do CORS da api em `www.transparencia.gov.br` isto se você possuir acesso a essa api do governo.

Caso não possua esse acesso, você pode fazer um "proxy" em php e fazer o ajax para este arquivo, onde este obteria os dados da api do governo. Na prática é bem simples, veja:

```php
<?php
// arquivo consulta.php

// Tratar get aqui
$codigo = $_GET['codigo'];

// faz a requisição
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.transparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/seguro-defeso-codigo?codigo='. $codigo .'&pagina=1');

echo $result;
```

A parte do ajax seria:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#btnBuscar').on('click', function () {
        $.get('consulta.php', {codigo: $('#cpf').val()}, function (resultado) {
            alert("Resultado obtido\nConsulte o console para mais detalhes");
            console.log(resultado);
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Onde `$('#btnBuscar')` seria o seletor do botão de busca e `$('#cpf')` seria o seletor do campo onde o usuário digita o código para buscar.